# Update MS Access non-updatable recordset form control via VBA SQL

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have MySQL ODBC datasource. I have datasheet view form or MySQL view which are build from 3 tables by joining them and summarizing some data (Totals).
Let's say I have Orders view with subtotals in them and I need to see full list of those orders and its summaries in simple datasheet view.
In this datasheet view I have `cmb` column `order_route` which are Lookup field to `routes` MySQL ODBC table.
Because of grouped data in my MySQL view I can't make any direct update to this view. It is fine.
What I want to do is - I want to left Control Source of this `cmb` column as it is to `vwOrdersDetails`.`route_id` BUT Row Source as SELECT `routes`.`id`,... FROM routes table.
So till now it is fine - I have grid with orders, its summaries and I have combobox which I can expand and to select Route I want.
The challenge is to run custom VBA SQL when I select value of this combobox. I need to disable default update behavior of this control and let it run my custom VBA event. Right now I can run this VBA event and order Route is updated, but I don't know how to disable that build-in update behavior because it is trying to update non-updatable recordset.
P.S. - NO! I don't want to make Updatable record-set without summaries in it. And i cant force user to open every record's Profile view just to update Route because it takes too many clicking.

Similar topic: [VBA Access: How to link an updatable recordset to an updatable FORM and save the changes in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650108/vba-access-how-to-link-an-updatable-recordset-to-an-updatable-form-and-save-the)

[image]

Comment: Is the control source property of the combobox a field name from your table or is it blank?

Comment: Just use an unbound control, and populate it on `Form_Current`.

Comment: I cant leave Control Source empty because i need to see actual Route in main grid. What do you mean with Unbound Control? I think the actual Route also will be empty in this case.

Comment: So what's the "default update behavior of this control" you need to disable?

Comment: When you select some other value (click event on item) Access is trying to update it, but it cant. And i get Non-Updatable recordset Error. I need to disable that event at all.